# ESRI File Geodatabase-Import Table without Geometry

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, excel

I have an excel spreadsheet that I need to use as the attribute table for a file geodatabase feature class. I know I can import a table to a file GDB but can I import the table as a feature class or to a feature class? If I have it as a feature class I will use the information in the attribute table to digitize my features.

Comment: Does your attribute table contain spatial info like X/Y coordinates?  Are these features going to be points, lines, or polygons?

Comment: It contains no spatial information, I want to digitize this at a later stage. The features will be polygons in the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is generally a bad idea to attempt to create a FeatureClass that has empty geometry.  You may get errors because the GDB is attempting to validate that spatial data.
Your best bet is to simply import the table using the [Table to Table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/table-to-table.htm) function.  This will create a Stand-alone Table in your geodatabase.  Prior to doing this, ensure you have a **UniqueID** for the table.
You can then [Create a Featureclass](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-feature-class.htm), with a Polygon geometry type, and your desired Spatial Reference.  Add a field for **UniqueID**.  You may then start to edit this layer.  Have your `Stand-alone Table` open, and refer to that when digitizing your polygons.  Then add the UniqueID to your Feature that corresponds to the row from the table you are digitizing.
Once you have completed, you will be able to join the two tables together, and use as necessary.  Or, you may join then export to a new featureclass so your Features and Attributes are all together.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are no spatial geometric info in your Excel table you will have to create the empty polygon feature class, create a common id field between the two layers, digitize the polygons, join non spatial table to the polygon feature class, and export out the joined layer to make it a permanent layer.